# gcc / g++ command does nothing and exits with code 1

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc, g++, mingw-w64

## gcc / g++ throws exit code 1 and does nothing

I tried to compile my **c++ / c** files using gcc / g++ !

It did nothing

- the command neither produced a.exe file
- it didn't throw any error ,(print anything to console)

> gcc myprogram.c

it showed no error message and moved to next line with Exit code 1.
The .exe file was also not created

the same thing happend for g++
So , I tried to manually run the command

same thing happened. (no output, no error)

**while running in command prompt**
it gave the following message in popup

> "The application was unable to start correctly (Oxc00000be). Click 0K
> to close the application."

ps:

*im using **windows 11**, mingw-64 compiler downloaded from github "**x86_64-13.1.0-release-posix-seh-msvcrt-rt_v11-rev1.7z**" ,I have **windows defender** on my pc , I tried to **turn off real-time scanning** and ran the command . It didn't work. neither it didn't show any log of blocking exe files, or gcc.exe, g++.exe*

*i had been using the same compiler for a few months, it didn't cause any trouble earlier, now it's not even working*

i can't compile my code now.

---

Comment: executable files not being created still very much sounds like an antivirus problem.

Comment: What is your compilation command and its full output?  (As text, not a picture)

Comment: Please, don't post images of code and errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: I disabled real-time protection , and also added my working folder to exclusions in defender.. Do i have to try something else?

Comment: @DrewDormann my command was gcc myprogram.c ... it didn't gave any msg or anything .. it just moved to next command line and returned a exit code 1

Comment: It seems that this command window doesn't show the whole output. Can you run your compilation commands in a plain terminal window?

Comment: @Gerhardh I did.. but no message was shown. I tried to run the same code in both powershell (with admin privileges) .. it didn't gave any output.  edit: When i ran it with commad prompt : it showed this msg in a popup window "The application was unable to start correctly (Oxc00000be). Click 0K
to close the application."

Comment: Can you delete the executable? `rm myprogram` or `del myprogram.exe` ... maybe there's a "locked" version of it already present on disk? Reboot, check running apps and *carefully* kill anything that looks like it needs to be killed.

Comment: The problem seems to be with gcc , g++ .. they dont even start if i give an input file.... i tried to give a non existing file name ... it did the same behaviour

Comment: Trash??? Really??? https://paste.pics/PH8S3 ... I used to have a script deleteing trash everytime I rebooted my computer :)

Comment: "mingw-64 compiler downloaded for github" What does that mean, did you build it yourself? Or did you download a binary built by some random Github person?

Comment: @Lundin its a repo for official mingw-64 builds. link : https://github.com/niXman/mingw-builds-binaries/releases

Comment: `0xc00000be` could be `STATUS_BAD_NETWORK_PATH` Do you have a UNC path or mapped network path in the PATH variable in the environment? Maybe a typo?

Comment: @infinull "Mingw64 for Windows 32" doesn't exactly build confidence though.

Comment: @Lundin Where did win 32 came in?

Comment: Yes, exactly... ask whoever named those files.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it right

You just have to move the path of **mingw/bin** folder in **environment variables** up

goto environment variables .. set the path of bin folder .. now move it all the way up.

This worked for me